# Expo - Is there a way to build an expo app to a .ipa file without an apple developer account?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, sideloading

I've created a simple personal project and don't intend to release it to the app store. Is there any way I can build the expo app to get a .ipa file I can sideload on to my iPhone without a paid apple developer account?

Comment: Be aware that an adhoc build with a free developer program membership will only run for 7 days and then you will need to rebuild and update the installed app